# Using ec2.py for dynamic inventory

Tags: macos, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ansible

I've managed to create a ec2 instance on the fly using ansible  -

tasks:

```
- name: Launch Instance
  ec2:
    group_id: "{{ item.group_id }}"
    count: 1
    instance_type: 't2.micro'
    image: '{{ item.image }}'
    wait: true
    region: 'us-east-1'
    aws_access_key: ''
    aws_secret_key: ''
    key_name: "{{ pem }}"
    instance_profile: "{{ profile }}"
  register: ec2
  with_items: ec2_instances
```

And when i run ec2.py --list i can see the json response. 
How do i use this in any ansible playbook. I want to add these dynamically create hosts to a file how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tag your instance(s) and then call your instance with tag using ansible.

First create a directory `filter_plugins` where your playbook exist and then copy this code inside the file with the name `get_ec2_info.py`:

```
from jinja2.utils import soft_unicode

'''
USAGE:
 - debug:
     msg: "{{ ec2.results | get_ec2_info('id') }}"
Some useful ec2 keys:
id
dns_name
public_ip
private_ip
'''

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'get_ec2_info': get_ec2_info,
        }

def get_ec2_info(list, ec2_key):
    ec2_info = []
    for item in list:
        for ec2 in item['instances']:
            ec2_info.append(ec2[ec2_key])
    return ec2_info
```

here is the modified code of your example:

```
- name: Launch Instance
  ec2:
    group_id: "{{ item.group_id }}"
    count: 1
    instance_type: 't2.micro'
    image: '{{ item.image }}'
    wait: true
    region: 'us-east-1'
    aws_access_key: ''
    aws_secret_key: ''
    key_name: "{{ pem }}"
    instance_profile: "{{ profile }}"
    instance_tags:
      Name: "myserver"
      Environment: "staging"
      Server_Role: "webserver"
  register: ec2
  with_items: ec2_instances

- name: Create SSH Group to login dynamically to EC2 Instance(s)
  add_host: 
    hostname: "{{ item }}"
    groupname: webserver
  with_items: "{{ ec2.results | get_ec2_info('public_ip') }}"

- name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the local host group (located at ./inventory/hosts)
  lineinfile:
    dest: "./inventory/hosts" 
    regexp: "{{ item }}" 
    insertafter: "[webserver]" 
    line: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ ec2.results | get_ec2_info('public_ip') }}"

- name: Wait for SSH to come up on EC2 Instance(s)
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ item }}" 
    port: 22 
    state: started
  with_items: "{{ ec2.results | get_ec2_info('public_ip') }}"
```

Set the `ec2.py` inventory as environment variables on the system(or you can call the inventory by `-i` parameter):

```
export ANSIBLE_HOSTS=/your-inventory-path/ec2.py
export EC2_INI_PATH=/your-inventory-path/ec2.ini
```

After that setup your SSH Key:

```
cp /tmp/mykey.pem ~/.ssh/
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
```

Now you can also use tags to call your instance (I am supposing that you are using Ubuntu instance please change the user accordingly):

```
ansible -m ping tag_Name_myserver -u ubuntu
```

or

```
ansible -m ping tag_Environment_staging -u ubuntu
```

or

```
ansible -m ping tag_Server_Role_webserver -u ubuntu
```

OR you can use this in your playbook like this:

```
- hosts: tag_Name_myserver
  become: yes
  remote_user: ubuntu
  roles:
    - your-role-here
```

Hope this will help you. For complete reference, please check these locations:

- [ansible-aws-roles](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-roles)
- [ansible-ec2](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-roles/blob/master/roles/ec2instance/tasks/main.yml)

Comment: TASK [Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the local host group (located at ./inventory/hosts)] ***
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined Error, in the future this will be a fatal error.: 'dict object' has no attribute 'instances'.
This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in 
ansible.cfg.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it now. but please make sure that inventory directory exists in the place from where you are executing the playbook and host file also exist inside that inventory directory so that it can write the ip into it.

Comment: TASK [Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the local host group (located at ./inventory/hosts)] ***
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'get_ec2_info'. String: {{ ec2.results | get_ec2_info('public_ip') }}"}

Comment: Did you create the directory filter_plugins where your playbook exist and then copy this code inside the file with the name get_ec2_info.py

Comment: Can you please marked the answer as valid so other can take advantage from it.

Comment: I've marked it. But it says - I need to earn 15 reputation points for my vote to be publicly visible.